# How do I organize my Processing code in separate files?

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to code a big project using processing. I want to separate the files that contain groups of classes and methods. How do I include the separated files in my main processing file? 
I'm looking for something similar to "#include" in c++.

Comment: do you mean `import`?

Comment: If they are in the same package you can use them directly too without import.

Comment: Thank you I guess import is what I was looking for.
@user1896769 How is a package defined? Is it defined by the folder that it's in? Do subfolders also get automatically included?

Comment: @AryanGoharzad packages names are derived from directory names, but subpackages are in no way special: classes in package `a.b` are not visible from classes in package `a`, and classes in package `a` are not visible from classes in package `a.b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java there may be only one (public) class per file. Classes are organized in packages, and packages are "nested" in a directory tree (just for convenience, since different packages are different, no matter where they are located).

Classes from other packages are not visible unless you *import* them. For instance, if you have your sources in `src`:

File `/src/a/b/Class1.java` contains:

```
package a.b;
public class Class1 {...}
```

In another class (let's say `/src/x/Class2.java`:

```
package x;
import a.b.Class1; //or import a.b.*;
public class Class2 {...}
```